# iOS Navigation between controllers/views with Login remembered

Tags: ios, authentication, uinavigationcontroller

I have A,B and C which are controllers that deal with user login. This would be the flow:

A->B

or

A->C

Then

B->Main

or

C->Main

From Main there should be a left button to logout and start all over from A again.
I understand that this could be accomplished using popToRootViewControllerAnimated.
The problem is that if the user is remembered in B/C (I have an UISwitch) then I would like to directly go to Main if the application is terminated and relaunched, so the root controller would be Main instead of A. So popToRootViewControllerAnimated wouldn't work.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why not just push main non-animated in your app delegate if the user is remembered?

Comment: If I just push the Main, then the left button (Logout) would not be able to pop to A.

Comment: I meant load A and then PUSH main to it like you are doing anyway, just without animation.